# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - protractor node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

Am trying to get text of all the files from a folder.But am facing the below error.Please help me resolve it.

```
verifyXZ = async function(){
              
    var listOfFiles = await getListOfElements(locator);
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    var file = await browser.get(listOfFiles[i].getText());
    console.log(file);
      
    }
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Sergey Pleshakov 5 : Please help here

Comment: Edit the question with the result of `console.log(listOfFiles)` as the first line in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that the attribute `listOfFiles` is receiving a `undefined` value, you'd have to check your logic. The code you've posted is missing a bracket, i've changed the scope of some variables, it should look like this:

```
verifyXZ = async function () {

    const listOfFiles = await getListOfElements(locator);
    for (let i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        const file = await browser.get(listOfFiles[i].getText());
        console.log(file);
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: If `listOfFiles` was undefined he would be getting an error while setting up the for loop `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Oh i see, so maybe the `listOfFiles[i].getText()` is returning `undefined`?

Comment: @Enslev   It has 1 file and listOfFiles.length is printing --> 1 .

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with this one, but you should promise to go over protractor documentation :)

You can't blindly type something and expect it to work. Always test your code, line by line. Don't type thousand of lines and try to debug all at once. And when you ping someone on stackoverflow, use `@` so I get a notification, I'm not checking every post in here

Here is what should work for you

```
verifyXZ = async function() {
  let listOfFiles = getListOfElements(locator); // I assume you tested your locator, and it works (1)
  let count = await listOfFiles.count(); // find out how many elements you have (2)
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) { // loop through every
    let file = await listOfFiles.get(i).getText()); // use get() (3)
    console.log(file);
  }
```

[1. by.xpath](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath)

[2. count()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count)

[3. get()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get)